# Post form with JSP + AJAX + MYSQL, without refresh page?

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp, page-refresh

I have problem with send form without refresh page in JSP using AJAX. How can I create AJAX to send this form, from index.jsp to send.jsp without refresh page ? Thanks for all your answers.

This is form code and it s work, without AJAX. (**index.jsp**)

```
<form id="dom-realitka-notifikacia"  action="send.jsp" method="post" >
          <div class="stred">
           <b class="cierna">E-mail:</b>      
            <input type="text"  class="form-control form-rovno" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Sem napíšte e-mail">
            <input type="hidden" value="domrealitka" id="tabulka" name="tabulka">
            <input type="hidden" value="<%= rs.getInt("id") %>" id="id_realitka" name="id_realitka">

          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Odoslať</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

And this is (**send.jsp**), work without AJAX and insert into MYSQL.

```
page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
page import="javax.mail.*"
page import="javax.mail.internet.*" 
page import="javax.sql.*"
page import="javax.naming.Context"
page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"
page import="java.sql.*"


            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            Connection con = null; 
            PreparedStatement ps = null; 
            ResultSet rs = null; 

           String email = request.getParameter("email");
           int id_realitka = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id_realitka"));
           String tabulka = request.getParameter("tabulka");



            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                System.out.println("nacitala sa driver");
                Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/janko");
                con = ds.getConnection();
                System.out.println("nacitala sa databaza");



                String sql = "INSERT INTO janko.notifikacia (email,  id_realitka, tabulka) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)"; 
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                ps.setString(1, email);
                ps.setInt(2, id_realitka);
                ps.setString(3, tabulka);

                ps.executeUpdate();


            con.close();

            } 

             catch(ClassNotFoundException e1) //ClassNotFoundException dame Class.forName a klikneme ctrl+space a e1 dopiseme hocico
            {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage()); //vypis spravy e1 do konzoly

            }
            catch(SQLException e2) //SQLException mame z DriverManager.getConnection po kliknuti ctrl+space a e2 dopiseme hocico
            {
                System.out.println(e2.getMessage()); //vypis spravy e2 do konzoly

            }

            finally{
                con = null; 
                rs = null;  
                ps = null;  
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

The form can be dynamically submitted easily using jQuery. Just include jQuery in your file and paste the following code in your HTML file.

```
<script>
$.ajax({url: "send.jsp", 
        data: $('#dom-realitka-notifikacia').serialize(),
        success: function(result){
        //do something like showing success message
    }});
</script>
```

This code will serialize your form data and send it to the concerned servlet. The servlet code remains the same.